# sshexec Remote command failed with exit status -1

Tags: ssh, cmd

I have the following line in  my xml code trying to kill a java process.

```
<sshexec command="kill something" failonerror="false"/>
```

and I sometimes get this error:

> [sshexec] Remote command failed with exit status -1

The process is not killed and therefore when I restart it again I get 2 instances of it not 1.

Could anyone help me with the meaning of the exit status?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Non zero exit status usually means that program finished with some error.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status

In order to debug this problem you may to login to your remote server and execute your kill command manually to see the error.